# How to send html format massage using wp_mail()?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I try to send mail using `wp_mail()`. For me is important the mail body contain the custom HTML template. For this purpose, I create the e-mail template, packed it into a file: `mailtpl.php` this file placed into the theme root. And in the `functions.php` I'm using this chunk of code:

```
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
$headers[] = 'From: '.get_bloginfo("name").' <'.get_bloginfo("admin_email").'>' . "\r\n";
$message = include 'mailtpl.php';

wp_mail( $email, 'Registration on the site '.get_bloginfo("name"), $message, $headers );
```

This code is triggered when a new user is registered. But an e-mail comes to the mailbox with no content. Just 1 number displayed in the mail body.

Please help me figure out why this is happening.

Comment: [Is there a way to send HTML formatted emails with WordPress' wp_mail() function?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27856/is-there-a-way-to-send-html-formatted-emails-with-wordpress-wp-mail-function)

Comment: @AlivetoDie I've seen this post already, but I can't get it, how this post connect with my issue? I used the  $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'; as you cant see in the code above,  The problem that a mail do not display content from file: mailtpl.php

Comment: Write the selected answer code in your theme `functions.php` and then go like questions code for formatting email. That's it

Comment: @AlivetoDie I tried to do something like this: 

$message = ''<table class="table1" width="438" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0 auto;">

.........

</table>" But there are display error in phpstorme

Comment: You can't include file in the body. Try using this function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: @Fresz Thanks I'm going to implement it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments the `file_get_contents()` is what was needed as you can't include a file in the email message.

```
$template = file_get_contents('mailtpl.php', true);

$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
$headers[] = 'From: '.get_bloginfo("name").' <'.get_bloginfo("admin_email").'>' . "\r\n";
$message = $template;

wp_mail( $email, 'Registration on the site '.get_bloginfo("name"), $message, $headers );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! Today I learned a new useful PHP function thanks to you.

Comment: Haha, no problem. Remember to use the php.net/manual it really makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for @Fresz comment, I used the:

```
$message = file_get_contents('mailtpl.php', true);
```

insted the:

```
$message = include 'mailtpl.php';
```

And the e-mail message starts forming in the correct way.

Comment: Nice :) I posted the answer too :P feel free to accept either of them :)